# Click event and separate JavaScript from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, dom-events

For a synoptic web application, I am trying to change an image when you click on. I have written a code as follows (in a jsp file) but I want to separate JavaScript from HTML (this next code works well):

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function ChangeState(){
            if(document.getElementById('imageStateBlue')!=null){
                var img=document.getElementById('imageStateBlue');
                img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: red');
                img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateRed');
                img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/red.png');}
            else{
                if(document.getElementById('imageStateRed')!=null){
                    var img=document.getElementById('imageStateRed');
                    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: blue');
                    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateBlue');
                    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png');}}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img alt='State: blue' id='imageStateBlue' onclick='ChangeState()' src='pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png'/>
</body>
```

So, I tried that (with the same js code in ChangeState.js)(this next code does not work well):

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='pages/synoptique/js/ChangeState.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img alt='State: blue' id='imageStateBlue' onclick='ChangeState()' src='pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png'/>
</body>
```

and that (these two next codes do not work well):

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='pages/synoptique/js/ChangeState.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img alt='State: blue' id='imageStateBlue' src='pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png'/>
</body>
```

with ChangeState.js like that:

```
function toRed(){
    var img=document.getElementById('imageStateBlue');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: red');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateRed');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/red.png');}
function toBlue(){
    var img=document.getElementById('imageStateRed');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: blue');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateBlue');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png');}
function imgClick(){
    document.getElementById('imageStateBlue').addEventListener('click', toRed, true);
    document.getElementById('imageStateRed').addEventListener('click', toBlue, true);}
window.addEventListener('load', imgClick, true);
```

but nothing works. It seems to do not be imported at the page loading. (When the codes do not work well, I mean the image does not change at the click).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the the click event correctly.

```
document.getElementById('imageStateBlue').addEventListener('click', toRed, true);
document.getElementById('imageStateRed').addEventListener('click', toBlue, true);}
```

Once you change, it, it removes the `id` from the event right? So, what you need to do is once you change the ID, reassign the event listener. So both in `toBlue` and `toRed` functions, redeclare the event listeners.

```
function toRed(){
    var img=document.getElementById('imageStateBlue');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: red');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateRed');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/red.png');
    document.getElementById('imageStateRed').addEventListener('click', toBlue, true);
}
function toBlue(){
    var img=document.getElementById('imageStateRed');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: blue');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateBlue');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png');
    document.getElementById('imageStateRed').addEventListener('click', toBlue, true);
}
```

And the first `imgClick` would fail, because one of the image is not existing. That may also cause to fail the event setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign have the handlers responding to id changes

```js
function ChangeState() {
  var img = this;
  if (/blue.png$/.test(img.src)) {
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: red');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateRed');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/red.png');
  } else {
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'State: blue');
    img.setAttribute('id', 'imageStateBlue');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png');
  }
}

function imgClick() {
  document.getElementById('imageState').addEventListener('click', ChangeState, true);
}
window.addEventListener('load', imgClick, true);
```

```html
<img alt='State: blue' id='imageState' src='pages/synoptique/src/images/blue.png' />
```